# Spreading a given value over a given length of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a `number` 27.50.
I want to spread it in an array `Result`, size of which is  2000.
The distribution of 27.50 in array `Result` shall start from 1 and end at 27.50.

```
number = 27.50;
Size = 2000;
Result = zeros(Size ,1);
```

I want it to distribute it in a such way that when  I do `cumsum` of `Result`, final index shall have 27.50 and when I do `sum` of `Result` it shall be equal to 27.50.

**Expected Result:**

```
tmp = cumsum(Result)
tmp(end) == 27.50 

sum(Result) == 27.50
```

**Question:**

Is there any possible way to do it? If yes please advice what method shall I use*

Comment: `Result = repmat(number/Size ,Size ,1);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do it in many ways.

As @rahnema1 mentioned you can use a uniform distribution:

```
repmat(number/Size ,Size ,1)
```

Or you can use also a Gaussian:

```
normcdf(0:Size,1000,100) %choose the parameters yo want
```

Or any other distribution you want.

The key point is that you must normalize your distribution in a way that the sum under it is equal to the value you want: `27.50` in your case.

Comment: Thank you sorted.